# Using secrets with docker is fine but fails for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I have a `Dockerfile` that uses secrets and I can successfully build the image using `docker build`.  However, when I try to build the same image using `docker-compose build` I get the error:

```
ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 4: Unknown flag: mount
```

This occurs on Ubuntu 20.04LTS (Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77,
docker-compose version 1.20.0-rc2, build 8c4af54).

On RHEL 7.9 (Docker version 20.10.7 build f0df350, docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c) a different error occurs:

```
[2/2] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=the_secret cat /run/secrets/the_secret:  
 #8 0.466 cat: /run/secrets/the_secret: No such file or directory
```

How can I use docker-compose to build my images that involve secrets?

**Build using docker** (works)

```
#!/bin/bash
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1


echo "I have a secret" > secret.txt
docker build --secret id=the_secret,src=./secret.txt .
```

**build using docker-compose** (fails)

```
export COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1


echo "I have a secret" > secret.txt
docker-compose build --no-cache test
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM python:3.8

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=the_secret cat /run/secrets/the_secret
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.6"

services:
    test:
        build: .
        secrets:
            - the_secret

secrets:
    the_secret:
        file: secret.txt
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile needs the syntax: `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge the docker documentation uses the dockerfile:1.2 syntax specification at https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/ so that should not be the problem.  Same problem arises when I change it as you suggest.

Comment: Just in case people come here looking for an answer, the syntax here looks nearly correct. The answer in the link below uses `context: .` rather than `build`, but a fix for this in docker-compose came in April 2022, so you need to be using docker-compose 2.5.0+:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280771/how-to-use-secrets-when-building-docker-compose-locally
The first answer in the above links out to the PRs in GitHub.