# How to use secrets when building docker compose locally

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-buildkit

I recently started using Buildkit to hide some env vars, and it worked great in prod by gha!

My Dockerfile now is something like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
...
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=my_secret,uid=1000 \
    MY_SECRET=$(cat /run/secrets/my_secret) \
    && export MY_SECRET
```

And my front was something like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build \
    --secret  id=my_secret,env="MY_SECRET"
```

And when I run this on my Github actions, it works perfectly.

But now, **the problem** here is when I try to build it locally. When performing a `docker-compose build` it fails. Of course, because I'm not passing in any secret so my backend (Dockerfile) won't be able to read it from `run/secrets/`.

What I've tried to do, so far, to accomplish the local build using `docker-compose build`:

**1. Working with Docker secrets:**

I basically tried doing:

```
$ docker swarm init
$ echo "my_secret_value" docker secret create my_secret -
```

I thought that saving a secret would fix the problem but didn't work. I still got the same error message:

> cat: can't open '/run/secrets/my_secret': No such file or directory

2. I also tried passing in the secret on my docker-compose file like the following but didn't work either:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: "."
      args:
        - "MY_SECRET"
  secrets:
      - my_secret
secrets:
  my_secret:
    external: true
```

3. I also tried storing the secret in a local file, but didn't work, the same error:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: "."
      args:
        - "MY_SECRET"
  secrets:
      - my_secret
secrets:
  my_secret:
    file: ./my_secret.txt
```

4. I also tried doing something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597742/6459968) something like this:

```
args:
    - secret=id=my_secret,src=./my_secret.txt
```

But still got the same error:

> cat: can't open '/run/secrets/my_secret': No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong to successfully perform a `docker-compose build`?

I'm aware that I can easily use two Dockerfiles, a Dockerfile to build in local and a Dockerfile to build in prod but I just want to use Buildkit as it is, by only modifying my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Does anyone have an idea about what am I missing to be able to build locally reading from `/run/secrets/`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Support for this was recently implemented in v2. See the below pull requests.

- https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9386
- https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/238

The provided example looks like this:

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: .
      secrets:
        - server-certificate
secrets:
  server-certificate:
    file: ./server.cert
```

So you are close, but you have to add the secret key under the build key.

Also keep in mind that you have to use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`, in order to use v2 which is built into the docker client.

Comment: Hey, I actually also tried this from version `3.8` and isn't working, got the error: `services.app.build contains unsupported option: 'secrets'` What do I have to do to get it working?

Comment: My docker desktop says that my compose version is `1.29.2`

Comment: @JonatanLavado, this  is a compose v2 feature. Use the build in command `docker compose` not `docker-compose` which is the python package. It works for me with `Docker Compose version v2.5.0`

Comment: I just updated my docker desktop and it seems to be working. I'll let you know. But a quick question, do you know if it's possible to pass an exported variable to the secrets property? I have my secret saved locally with `$ export VAR`. Is there a property to define it without using a file?

Comment: @JonatanLavado, there is currently no support for variables. There is an open issue for this. It may be available in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly since which version of compose, but you can pass secrets as environment like this:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      secrets:
        - BUILD_SECRET
secrets:
  BUILD_SECRET:
    environment: BUILD_SECRET
```

Then handle in `Dockerfile` like this:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=BUILD_SECRET BUILD_SECRET="$(cat /run/secrets/BUILD_SECRET)" \
    echo "BUILD_SECRET=$BUILD_SECRET"
```

Now you just put `BUILD_SECRET` to `.env` and `docker-compose build` will read it by itself.